# How to put two trapezoids one beside another using DIVs and css

Tags: html, css, each

I'm trying to put two `div`s beside to look like on attached picture.

It can`t be a svg file, it must be done with css and divs, any idea?!

[image]

**EDIT:**

**My code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
*, *:before, *:after{ 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
} 
.left{ 
    position: relative; 
    height: 170px; 
    width: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 

    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg); 
    transform: skew(0deg); 
    border-top: 56px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 0px transparent; 
    border-right: 144px solid #ffaf32; 
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent; 
}


.right{ 
    position: relative; 
    height: 200px; 
    width: 0px; 

    border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 300px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55); 
    border-right: 0px transparent; 
    border-bottom: 49px solid transparent; 
}




</style>



<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

How to put it beside like on image?

UPDATE :

Never mind I did it.

```
<style type="text/css">
*, *:before, *:after{ 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
} 
.left{ 
    position: relative; 
    height: 170px; 
    width: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 

    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg); 
    transform: skew(0deg); 
    border-top: 56px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 0px transparent; 
    border-right: 144px solid #ffaf32; 
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent; 

 float: left;

            text-align: right;
            width: 80px;

}

.right{ 
    position: relative; 
    height: 170px; 
    width: 0px; 

    border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 300px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55); 
    border-right: 0px transparent; 
    border-bottom: 49px solid transparent; 

            margin-left: 144px;

}

</style>

<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: Several...but we're not here to write your code for you. Show us what you have attempted so far and we might be able to help you out with the tricky sections.

Comment: Drawing a trapezoid is very easy. A little bit of search will give you css tricks site's link. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/4CKW5/ 
Post some code, people are more likely to help you. This should be enough to get you started

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it when you can. Don't just post your solution in your original post and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but based on the comments posted, I came up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4CKW5/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="trapezoid-left"></div>
<div id="trapezoid-right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div { width: 0px; border: 0px solid Green; float: left}

#trapezoid-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 200px solid red;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}
#trapezoid-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 400px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

answer :

```
<style type="text/css">
*, *:before, *:after{ 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
} 
.left{ 
    position: relative; 
    height: 170px; 
    width: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 

    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg); 
    transform: skew(0deg); 
    border-top: 56px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 0px transparent; 
    border-right: 144px solid #ffaf32; 
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent; 

 float: left;

            text-align: right;
            width: 80px;

}


.right{ 
    position: relative; 
    height: 170px; 
    width: 0px; 

    border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 300px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55); 
    border-right: 0px transparent; 
    border-bottom: 49px solid transparent; 

            margin-left: 144px;

}




</style>

<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```